# Json Net hierarchy class

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, json-deserialization

I am using Newtonsoft.Json on my VB.Net, and having trouble with json deserialization.

Totally a noob on this. A simple class hierarchy, I can do it... but a more complex like the one below, totally an idiot.

Can someone help me to build the serialize class hierarchy from this JSON??

```
{
    "user": {
        "user_id": 123456,
        "total": 100,
        "rewards": 0
    },
    "workers": {
        "1": {
            "worker_name": "rainfall_home",
            "rate": 0,
            "shares": 0
        },
        "2": {
            "worker_name": "rainfall_office",
            "rate": 7358.71,
            "shares": 96564
        },
        "3": {
            "worker_name": "rainfall_rig",
            "rate": 0,
            "shares": 77208
        },
        "4": {
            "worker_name": "rainfall_s11",
            "rate": 178365.22,
            "shares": 3760356
        },
        "5": {
            "worker_name": "rainfall_s12",
            "rate": 196537.7,
            "shares": 4152710
        }
    },
    "total": {
        "total_user": 5,
        "record_date": 2
    }
}
```

And how do I get the workers length(total) and loop with it, so i can get record for each worker? Since worker can keep adding up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying to get the total number of workers and you are saying that workers can keep adding up, then I would propose you to restructure your JSON (if you have scope to modify) so that the workers can be managed as an `array` instead of adding it like an `object` each time a new worker is needed to add to JSON. Please see the proposed JSON below:

```
{
    "user": {
        "user_id": 123456,
        "total": 100,
        "rewards": 0
    },
    "workers": [
        {
            "worker_name": "rainfall_home",
            "rate": 0,
            "shares": 0
        },
        {
            "worker_name": "rainfall_office",
            "rate": 7358.71,
            "shares": 96564
        },
        {
            "worker_name": "rainfall_rig",
            "rate": 0,
            "shares": 77208
        },
        {
            "worker_name": "rainfall_s11",
            "rate": 178365.22,
            "shares": 3760356
        },
        {
            "worker_name": "rainfall_s12",
            "rate": 196537.7,
            "shares": 4152710
        }
    ],
    "total": {
        "total_user": 5,
        "record_date": 2
    }
}
```

Now your new classification is below:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public User user { get; set; }
    public List<Worker> workers { get; set; }
    public Total total { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int rewards { get; set; }
}

public class Worker
{
    public string worker_name { get; set; }
    public double rate { get; set; }
    public int shares { get; set; }
}

public class Total
{
    public int total_user { get; set; }
    public int record_date { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can easily loop through each worker to get one's details like below:

```
string json = "YOUR_JSON_STRING";
RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject> ( json );

Console.WriteLine("Total no. of workers: {0}", rootObject.workers.Count);

foreach ( Worker worker in rootObject.workers )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Rate: {1}, Shares: {2}", worker.worker_name, worker.rate.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), worker.shares);
}
```

Comment: The JSON data is from an outside API, so i cannot change the format.

For the worker part it gave me an error...
It said something about "The type require a JSON array.. to deserialize correctly".

Any thoughts???

Comment: I have posted another answer to fulfill your need. Please have a look at [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22195247/1977104)!

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON data is from an outside API, then you can classify it like below:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public User user { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Worker> workers { get; set; }
    public Total total { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int rewards { get; set; }
}

public class Worker
{
    public string worker_name { get; set; }
    public double rate { get; set; }
    public int shares { get; set; }
}

public class Total
{
    public int total_user { get; set; }
    public int record_date { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can easily loop through each worker to get one's details like below:

```
string json = "YOUR_JSON_STRING";
RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject> ( json );

Console.WriteLine("Total no. of workers: {0}", rootObject.workers.Count);

foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, Worker> worker in rootObject.workers )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Rate: {1}, Shares: {2}", worker.Value.worker_name, worker.Value.rate.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), worker.Value.shares);
}
```

Comment: i use php instead, it gives me more flexibility with this json thingy.  :P